# How to find the exact match within a match

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I am trying to match a credit card number using a regex. This is what I have:

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile('(?:\\d[ -]*?){13,16}');
Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(strSource);
while (myMatcher.find()) {
... do something ...
}
```

This works fine for most cases, but there's one case where I am having an issue. If the credit card number itself is preceded by a number followed by a dash or space, then myMatcher.find() finds the "first" match, but not the "second" match. For example, if strSource is :

4-4111 1111 1111 1111

Then myMatcher.find() returns '4-4111 1111 1111'. But that's the only match it finds, it does not find '4111 1111 1111 1111'. So is there a way to force myMatcher.find() to find a match within a match?

Answer (score 2):

You can use capture groups (`(expression)`) to get more specific matching information. A simple example:

```
String input = 'Test 1234';
Matcher m = Pattern.compile('Test (\\d+)').matcher(input);
if (m.find())
{
    system.debug(m.group());
    system.debug(m.group(0)); // same as m.group()
    system.debug(m.group(1));
}
```

You should see:

> Test 1234
>   Test 1234
>   1234

The first explicit capturing group returns just your digits. There is always an implicit zero-index group which matches the whole expression.

The counter to a capturing group is an non-capturing group (`(?:expression)`). However, you don't really need either here. More later.

As for your example, it shouldn't actually give the return value you state in your post. If I change my input string and matcher to yours, I get a different output: `4-4111 1111 1111`. That is expected behavior, since you specified a maximum of 16 characters. It seems what you really want is groups of 4 characters separated by space or dash characters. That expression doesn't really need (non-)capturing groups at all:

```
String input = '4-4111 1111 1111 1111';
Matcher m = Pattern.compile('(?:\\d{4}[ -]?){4}').matcher(input);
if (m.find())
{
    system.debug(m.group());
}
```

The above script outputs:

```
4111 1111 1111 1111
```

Comment: Sorry for showing up late .. This works well. But I faced one case and it says like "9876727323 4111 1111 1111 1111" which should return "4111 1111 1111 1111" but returning "7672732341111111" .. please share your comments on this @adrian